# Grunt watch FSEventStreamStart error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I try running grunt watch and I get this error -

```
2015-09-07 18:09 grunt[5461] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)
```

Gruntfile looks like this -

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        babel: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                stage: 0
            },
            files: {
                expand: true,
                src: ['scripts/**/*.es6.js'],
                ext: '.js',
                dest: 'static'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            files: ['**/*'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            },
            babel: {
                files: ['scripts/**/*.es6.js'],
                tasks: 'babel'
            },
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
}
```

What is happening?